# Galego: dialeto do Português ou dialeto do Espanhol?

Tags: português-europeu, origem-histórica, castelhano, galego

Por que cargas d'água o Galego tem sido historicamente classificado como dialeto do Espanhol e não do Português?

As similaridades (de construção, de vocábulos e de fonologia) parecem ser maiores com o Português do que com o Espanhol.

Alguém já deve ter parado para analisar detidamente isso. Há alguma indicação de referência bibliográfica sobre esse tópico?

Caso seja conturbada a minha observação, por que cargas d'água o Galego continua sendo classificado como dialeto do Espanhol, ao invés de passar à condição de parentesco com o Português?

Comment: Isso é verdade? O galego alguma vez foi classificado como dialeto do espanhol? O que eu sempre li foi que existiu o galaico-português, que a partir do fim da Idade Média divergiu entre galego e português.

Comment: @Jacinto Uma pesquisa bastante preguiçosa da minha parte me permitiu encontrar este trecho na [Wikipedia Galega](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_galega): "O réxime franquista arruinará o soño da recuperación social do idioma endurecendo as leis e perseguindo aqueles usos que se recuperaran no primeiro terzo do século. A doutrina nacionalcatólica aludirá ao galego -xunto co catalán, éuscaro, asturiano etc.- como ***dialecto*** e eliminarao con saña das escolas e da vida pública."   Os grifos são meus.

Comment: Parece-me que *dialecto* não pode ser aí interpretado como *dialeto do espanhol*; por exemplo, o euscaro, a língua basca, que nem sequer é indo-europeu, jamais poderia ser entendido como dialeto do espanhol. De qualquer modo isso foi apenas a política fascista, que durou uns 40 anos, de supressão de todas as línguas que não o castelhano.

Comment: Até a presente data, tudo o que li sobre o Galego é aquilo que Jacinto mencionou acima: a língua original, o galaico-português, deu origem ao galego e ao português.

Comment: @MarceloVentura o Galego não é um dialeto, é uma língua. Podes clarificar, na tua pergunta, quem o tem «historicamente classificado» como um dialeto do Espanhol?

Comment: O galego nunca, que saiba eu, tinha classificação de dialeto do castelhano, nim nos tempos medievais. A pergunta era mas bem se fosse ou não dialeto do português, e hoje é bastante evidente que é língua. Chamá-lo dialeto do castelhano é cosa puramente dos espanhóis super nacionalistas, mas não se funda na linguística (nenhum linguista sério o relacionaria mais com o castelhano).

Comment: Em inglês *dialect* pode significar língua minoritária, então neste sentido "Spanish dialect" pode significar qualquer língua regional da Espanha. Mas não estou a encontrar este significado em dicionários portugueses nem espanhóis. No francês sim. De qualquer forma, a questão de uma idioma ser língua ou dialeto pode tem más a ver com política do que ciência; há linguistas que deixam a questão de língua/dialeto para os politicos, dizendo que [«uma língua é um dialeto com um exército ou marinha.»](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uma_l%C3%ADngua_%C3%A9_um_dialeto_com_um_ex%C3%A9rcito_ou_marinha)

Comment: just want to put out that in English, Basque could be a "Spanish Dialect" (that is to say, a dialect from Spain) but not a "Dialect of Spanish".  Então por analogia talvez é certo falar que o Galego é um dialeto Espanhol, mas que não é um dialeto do Espanhol.

Comment: @DanGetz os linguistas fazem (tanto em inglés, que é a minha língua materna, como em português) uma distinção entre língua e dialeto.  Mas é em fazer a distinção onde pode haver discussão entre eles.  O facto de que os falantes ignorantes do inglês tendem a confundir as palavras não as roubam do seu significado técnico.  Muitos anglo-falantes dizem «literally» para dizer «figurativamente» (que é, literalmente, o contrário), e todos entendem o uso, e mesmo aparece no dicionário assim, mas segue sendo algo censurable formalmente.  Assim é o uso de *dialeto* por *língua* no inglês.

Comment: @Some_Guy Simplesmente não é assim no inglês.  Jamais diria (nem ouvi) alguém dizer no inglês que o euskera fosse dialeto espanhol.  Podemos falar (e fala-se sim muito) das *línguas espanhois*, que inclui o castelhano, galego, asturiano, valenciano/catalão, aranês, aragonês e euskera.

Comment: @guifa Just as Italian is said to be Portuguese’s cousin and Spanish its sister, it probably makes sense to look at the [genetic relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_relationship_(linguistics)) between Portuguese and Galician here as if we were drawing up cladograms for related taxa. What was the last common shared ancestor tongue between Portuguese and Galician, and when did it flourish? Consider Alfonso X’s *Cantigas* for example. Was it 300 years ago? 700? However you measure things, we’re probably talking “half-identical” twin sisters here, if you will excuse the allusion.

Answer (score 7):

O que dificulta uma resposta à tua pergunta é que, linguisticamente, nunca foi classificado como tal, e hoje  não é considerado dialeto nem do português nem do castelhano. É certo que muitos *españolistas* queriam (e ainda, na verdade, querem) designar o castelhano como espanhol e as outras línguas no país dialetos dele, um exemplo pode ser encontrado [nesta entrevista](http://www.vozbcn.com/2008/08/13/3461/sergio-catalan-dialecto-idioma/) que cito:

> ¿Cuántos idiomas habla?
>   — Bien, sólo el castellano.
>   ¿El catalán tampoco?
>   — Sí, pero el catalán es un dialecto, no es un idioma, igual que el gallego. Es como el asturiano. Eso no son idiomas. Yo creo que son dialectos, no los considero idiomas.
>
> **Em português**
>   Quantas línguas fala?
>   — Pois, só o castelhano.
>   O catalão não?
>   — Sim, mas o catalão é um dialeto, não é língua, igual ao galego. É como o asturiano. Aquelas não são línguas. Acho que são dialetos, não os considero línguas.

É um pensamento muito forte para algumas pessoas na Espanha.  Mas linguisticamente, é facto simples que o galego e o português foram, num momento não muito afastado de agora, uma só língua.<sup>1</sup>  Mas ao longo do tempo, as duas foram afastando-se pouco a pouco. Chamá-los língua ou dialeto, aí já é mais difícil dizer. Não há nenhum sistema linguístico-científico para dizermos exatamente o que constitui uma língua ou um dialeto.<sup>2</sup>

O que podemos dizer, desde uma perspetiva linguística, é que o galego é muito mais perto do português do que do asturiano ou do castelhano, e que o português fica muito mais perto do galego do que do mirandês ou do castelhano.

Quiçá seria possível dizer que o português e o galego são dialetos duma língua singular, mas acho que historicamente seria melhor dizer que o português é dialeto do galego, por a data de fundação de Portugal ser depois da da Galiza.  :-)

---

<sup>1.  E naquele momento, foi distinguido do romance —o castelhano antigo—, como podemos ver no caso de Afonso X usar essa língua para compor as suas famosas *Cántigas de Santa Maria*, apesar de usar normalmente o romance ou o latim.</sup>
<sup>2. Por exemplo, não há muita razão nem geográfica nem linguística, mas acho que eu diria facilmente que o galego e o português são línguas diferentes se alguém me perguntasse. Não obstante, o português europeu e o brasileiro são-me muito mais diferentes do que o português europeu e o galego, especialmente ao falarmos do português do norte do pais, e acho que quase todos diríamos que estes dois portugueses são dois dialetos de uma língua comum.</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta! Ela foi muito elucidativa.

Comment: Acho que a coisa virou política muito tempo atrás. Eu concordo com a sua resposta. É bem engraçado para mim, porque sabendo falar as duas línguas (sem misturar), sempre me dá a impressão, ao ouvrir o galego, que estão misturadas. Entendo tudo, mas não sei falar.

Comment: Toma, guifa, espero que ajude. Participa mais, que a gente dá uma [polidela](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/polir) no que for preciso! :)

Answer (score 3):

É mais acertado dizer que o galego e o português são codialetos de uma mesma língua, o [romance galaico-português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_galego-portuguesa) registrado nas [Cantigas de Santa Maria](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria) e em alguns cancioneiros medievais, como [o da Vaticana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancioneiro_da_Vaticana).

Comment: Obrigado!  Com a informação que você apresentou, é possível estabelecer um ancestral comum que aproxima Português e Galego.

Comment: @MarceloVentura quando pretender alterar o sentido da resposta convém perguntar primeiro ao autor se pode, ou avisa-lo que algo não está bem. A sua edição altera o sentido da resposta e por isso eu reverti.

Comment: Obrigado, @JorgeB.! Foi vacilo meu mesmo.  Acabei empolgando. Foi mal.  =D

Comment: Não seria mais adequado dizer que "o galego e o português são codialetos que derivaram de uma mesma língua, o romance galaico-português registrado nas Cantigas de Santa Maria e em alguns cancioneiros medievais, como o da Vaticana"?

Comment: P.s.: Perdão pela edição que eu fiz e que o Jorge B. acertadamente desfez.  Não foi intencional, mas foi rude da minha parte.

Comment: @MarceloVentura muito bem :)

Comment: Perdão pela demora em responder; dizer que “derivam de uma mesma língua” ou que “são uma mesma língua” depende em estabelecer quando a língua mãe dá lugar à filha, se dá. Como, pessoalmente, consigo entender (recitando em voz alta) a maioria dessas cantigas desses códices, não creio que seja mudado o suficiente para serem línguas novas. Mas é certamente uma questão espinhosa.

Answer (score 1):

Galego teve origem no norte de Espanha na região da Galiza.
Em algumas regiões fronteiriças (norte e nordeste) e dado a amizade entre as populações (fomentadas pelo desprezo á policia e ambas ditaduras fascistas (Franco e Salazar) os dois lados da fronteira falam Galego. Existem algumas diferenças entre o que se fala em Espanha comparado com Portugal mas devem-se sobretudo a conexões com a língua mãe.

Notem que Galego, Castelhano e são línguas de origem antiga, existindo teorias que seriam usadas pelos habitantes da zona (Galicia e Castilla) antes da separação dos dois países.

Podem encontrar explicação detalhada em:
http://www.omniglot.com/writing/galician.htm

Comment: husoi, não vejo como é que isto responde à pergunta feita: saber se `o galego é dialeto português ou espanhol?`. Talvez possas editar a pergunta para tornar isso claro.