# Porquê cargas d'águas?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica

Raul Seixas fala/canta em [Sapato 36](https://www.letras.mus.br/raul-seixas/79238/):

> Por que cargas d'águas você acha que tem o direito. De afogar tudo
>   aquilo que eu sinto em meu peito. Você só vai ter o respeito que quer
>   na realidade no dia em que você souber respeitar a minha vontade[...]

Dentre, também, outras frases<sup>[1](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/galego-dialeto-do-portugu%C3%AAs-ou-dialeto-do-espanhol)</sup> que podem ser formadas com a mesma expressão. De onde surgiu esse tal de "cargas d'águas"?

Comment: adicionando informação -> https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/por-que-carga-de-agua/10814

Comment: Imagino que fulano muito pobre nem tinha burro para carregar água nos tempos de outrora. Então ficava aquele peso imenso nas costas do pobrezinho.....:)

Comment: Uma boa pergunta. Nunca me perguntei o porquê.  Mas eu sempre ouvi "água" no singular ("cargas d'água").

Comment: Fica ainda mais pesado, então. :)

Comment: O @Lambie tem toda razão. huehue =D

Comment: A Lambie. Foi a ideia que me veio. :)

Comment: @Lambie Sorry! xD

Comment: @Lambie, *carga de água* também significa chuvada forte. Foi sempre a chuvada forte que eu associei a expressão.

Answer (score 1):

O Dicionário Informal [fornece](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/n%E3o+sei+por+que+cargas+d%27%E1gua/) a seguinte explicação:

> A expressão data de fins do século XIII, quando começaram as primeiras navegações portuguesas em águas do Atlântico norte. Região sujeita a súbitas tempestades, era freqüente que as naus se dirigissem às ilhas açorianas ou de Madeira, e acabassem chegando às costas marroquinas ou senegalesas. Daí a expressão significar "desconhecer como algo se passou".

Comment: Não é uma fonte confiável, muito menos acadêmica. Coloco a postagem mais como sugestão que como resposta.

Comment: Concordo que essa explicação do dicionário informal é duvidosa. Eles nem sequer demonstram que a expressão já estava em uso no sXIII; e as viagens para a Madeira e Açores começaram só no sXV. Portanto aquilo é só um palpite, um palpite suspeitosamente elaborado. E já que estamos numa de palpites, parece-me mais provável que as *cargas de água* sejam só um eufemismo substituindo *raio* ou *diabo* (*por que raio/diabo você acha que tem o direito*).

Comment: Bons pontos, @Jacinto. E infelizmente minhas buscas simples na internet não revelaram fontes melhores que corroborassem a história ou oferecessem alternativas melhor embasadas. Pode mesmo bem ser um eufemismo aleatório - talvez que soasse como algum palavrão da época (como hoje há os que dizem "carvalho" ao invés de "caralho").

Comment: Eu dei uma vista de olhos pelo Google Books, e só encontrei a expressão a partir de finais do sXIX, na forma "carga d'água". Naturalmente, ela poderia estar em uso já há séculos, e não aparecer por escrito no Goolge Books.

Comment: *Carga de água* ('chuvada forte') até tem algo que ver com raios. Mas nisto de expressões a imaginação popular não tem limites. Por exemplo, eu não fazia ideia da quantidade de [variantes que já existiram da expressão "macacos me mordam"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/qual-a-origem-da-express%C3%A3o-macacos-me-mordam).